Does the mean value theorem of the potential on a sphere hold for relativistic charge movements?
Imagine a sphere of radius $R$ centered at the origin, and a charge $q$ at some location on the $z$ axis outside the sphere.
When Laplace's equation $\nabla^2 \phi$ holds, it seems we can use the mean value theorem and state that the potential at the center of the sphere from charge $q$ is simply the mean value of the potential on the entire surface of the sphere from charge $q$. However, what happens when the charge suddenly starts moving relativistically away from the sphere?
My hypothesis is this: The $E$ field is redshifted in the direction of the sphere, which means there's a smaller flux of $E$ approaching the sphere. Then at the instant that smaller flux enters the sphere, there is a comparatively greater flux leaving the sphere from the other side from the original charge $q$ because the speed of light hasn't crossed the whole sphere yet.
Therefore, the sphere acts as if it has a net positive flux out through it which implies a higher potential at the center by Gauss' law.
However, an observer sitting in the middle of the sphere, if they try to observe the "mean potential" across the sphere, tries 'sampling' both sides of the sphere at once. He samples the backside of the sphere and the information comes to him at the speed of light, and at the same time, he samples the front of the sphere. BUT by the time the information reaches him, it has traveled a distance $R$ and therefore the smaller flux is at the center of the sphere now.
So would I be right in saying that there is a relativistic correction and the mean value property doesn't hold anymore? The observer at the center where we measure $\phi$ sees a net outward flux.
Would be great if someone could explain.

When you have charges in motion, you need to use both a scalar potential $\phi$ and a vector potential $\mathbf{A}$. Then the answer to your question is ill-defined, because $(\phi, \mathbf{A})$ has a gauge redundancy.
For example, in Lorenz gauge $\partial^\mu A_\mu = 0$, we have
$$\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial t^2} - \nabla^2 \phi = \rho$$
so that the answer to your question is no, since $\phi$ doesn't satisfy Laplace's equation away from charge. But in Coulomb gauge $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A} = 0$, we have
$$- \nabla^2 \phi = \rho$$
exactly, no matter how the charges are moving, so that the answer to your question is yes. The root cause of the ambiguity is that $\phi$ is not a directly measurable quantity.
